# How to save the data entered in JTable so that it remains even after we exit the application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, textfield

I'm new to net beans, I've created an app which consists of a JTable, 3 text fields and a button to insert the values entered in the text filed to the JTable. Everything works fine till now, but the moment I exit the application and re open it, the data entered previously gets deleted.
Is there a way that would save the data entered in the JTable so it remains even after exiting the app??

Comment: _"but the moment I exit the application and re open it, the data entered previously gets deleted."_ - You need to store the data in a file or a database and retrieve the data upon opening the program if you want it to show up on open

Answer (score 5):

For that purposes you need to store data in some place(db, file, or something other). The easiest way to serialize data from `TableModel` to file and then restore that to `JTable`. Try next simple example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    private JTable t1;

    public Example(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String...strings ){
        new Example();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        t1 = new JTable(getModel());

        add(new JScrollPane(t1),BorderLayout.NORTH);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                storeTableModel((DefaultTableModel) t1.getModel());
            }
        });
    }

    private TableModel getModel() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(3,3);
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\test"));
            Vector data = (Vector) ois.readObject();
            Vector<Object> cols = new Vector<>();
            for(int i=1;i<=data.size();i++){
                cols.add(i);
            }
            model.setDataVector(data, cols);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  finally{
            if(ois != null)
                try {
                    ois.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
        }
        return model;
    }

    public void storeTableModel(DefaultTableModel model) {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\test"));
            oos.writeObject(model.getDataVector());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  finally{
            if(oos != null)
                try {
                    oos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The data which you inserted into the `JTable` does not persists until and unless you save that data in file system or DB. So before exiting the application, you will have to first save that data into any file system or DB and then at the startup of `JTable` you need to again fetch that data from the respective storage system.